ng-content does not show component with host attribute
I'm trying to understand why ng-content doesn't show component with a host attribute.
If you inspect the generated HTML DOM, the attribute is present in the host tag, but the ng-content does not have any children.
@EDIT:
After @Naren Murali's answer, I added this edit to make my objective clearer. My idea is to not have to pass the middle-region attribute again when adding position-middle as a child of position-panel, because position-middle already has the attribute in the host tag.
position-panel.component
@Component({
    selector: "position-panel",
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    template: `
        <div class="position-panel-component">
            <div class="start-content">
                <ng-content select="[start-region]"></ng-content>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-content">
                <ng-content select="[middle-region]"></ng-content>
            </div>
            <div class="end-content">
                <ng-content select="[end-region]"></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: `
        .position-panel-component {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;

            > .start-content,
            > .middle-content,
            > .end-content {
                display: flex;
                height: 100%;
                justify-content: space-between;
                width: 100%;
            }

            > .start-content {
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                align-items: center;
            }

            > .middle-content {
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            > .end-content {
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: end;
                align-items: center;
            }

        }
    `
})
export class PositionPanelComponent {}

position-middle.component
@Component({
    selector: "position-middle",
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
    host: {
        "middle-region": "",
    },
})
export class PositionMiddleComponent {}

home.component
@Component({
    selector: "home",
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    template: `
        <div class="header-bar">
            <position-panel>
                <ng-container start-region> <!-- This works and displays -->
                    <button>Start 1</button>
                    <button>Start 2</button>
                    <button>Start 3</button>
                </ng-container>
                <position-middle> <!-- This doesn't work and doesn't display! In the DOM <div class="middle-content"> of position-panel is generated without children -->
                    <button>Middle 1</button>
                    <button>Middle 2</button>
                    <button>Middle 3</button>
                </position-middle>
                <div end-region> <!-- This works and displays -->
                    <button>End 1</button>
                    <button>End 2</button>
                    <button>End 3</button>
                </div>
            </position-panel>


            <!-- In the DOM position-middle is generated with the middle-region attribute -->
            <position-middle> 
                 <button>Middle 1</button>
                <button>Middle 2</button>
                <button>Middle 3</button>
            </position-middle>

        </div>
    `
})
export class HomeComponent {}

In the position-middle component, I have already tried assigning the attribute to the host tag in different ways, but none of them worked
host: {
    "[attr.middle-region]": "", // I receive error: AssertionError: Unsupported reification of ir.Expression kind: EmptyExpr
},
hostDirectives: [
    PositionMiddleDirective // The middle-region attribute is simply not generated in the DOM       
]


I tried out your example, all I had to do was add the attribute middle-region to the position-middle element and it worked great!
I also added the custom directive which changes the background color in intervals and this also gets applied with no issues. Working example below!
FULL CODE:
DIRECTIVE:
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPositionMiddle]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PositionMiddleDirective {
  colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.changeColor(el);
  }

  changeColor(el: ElementRef) {
    setInterval(() => {
      el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor =
        this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
    }, 1000);
  }
}

POSITION PANEL
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'position-panel',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
      <div class="position-panel-component">
          <div class="start-content">
              <ng-content select="[start-region]"></ng-content>
          </div>
          <div class="middle-content">
              <ng-content select="[middle-region]"></ng-content>
          </div>
          <div class="end-content">
              <ng-content select="[end-region]"></ng-content>
          </div>
      </div>
  `,
  styles: `
      .position-panel-component {
          display: flex;
          height: 100%;
          justify-content: space-between;
          width: 100%;

          > .start-content,
          > .middle-content,
          > .end-content {
              display: flex;
              height: 100%;
              justify-content: space-between;
              width: 100%;
          }

          > .start-content {
              flex-direction: row;
              justify-content: flex-start;
              align-items: center;
          }

          > .middle-content {
              flex-direction: row;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
          }

          > .end-content {
              flex-direction: row;
              justify-content: end;
              align-items: center;
          }

      }
  `,
})
export class PositionPanelComponent {}

POSITION MIDDLE
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PositionMiddleDirective } from '../position-middle.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'position-middle',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: '<ng-content />',
  styles: [
    `
    :host {
      padding-bottom: 10px; /* to highlight the changing background-color*/
    }
  `,
  ],
  host: {
    'middle-region': '', // I receive error: AssertionError: Unsupported reification of ir.Expression kind: EmptyExpr
  },
  hostDirectives: [
    PositionMiddleDirective, // The middle-region attribute is simply not generated in the DOM
  ],
})
export class PositionMiddleComponent {}

MAIN
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { PositionPanelComponent } from './app/position-panel/position-panel.component';
import { PositionMiddleComponent } from './app/position-middle/position-middle.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [PositionPanelComponent, PositionMiddleComponent],
  template: `
  <div class="header-bar">
      <position-panel>
          <ng-container start-region> <!-- This works and displays -->
              <button>Start 1</button>
              <button>Start 2</button>
              <button>Start 3</button>
          </ng-container>
          <position-middle middle-region> <!-- changed here! -->
              <button>Middle 1</button>
              <button>Middle 2</button>
              <button>Middle 3</button>
          </position-middle>
          <div end-region> <!-- This works and displays -->
              <button>End 1</button>
              <button>End 2</button>
              <button>End 3</button>
          </div>
      </position-panel>


      <!-- In the DOM position-middle is generated with the middle-region attribute -->
      <position-middle> 
           <button>Middle 1</button>
          <button>Middle 2</button>
          <button>Middle 3</button>
      </position-middle>

  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

My idea is to not have to pass the middle-region attribute again when adding position-middle as a child of position-panel, because position-middle already has the attribute in the host tag.

@sartoz The attributes specified in host are not visible to ng-content so it does not work! we have to specify the attribute on the position-middle component!
